# Viewing the full contents of a file Unix

Tags: unix

I want to be able to see all lines of text in a file, originally i only needed the top of the file and had been using

head -n 50 'filename.txt'

I could just do   head -n 1000 as most files contain less than this but would prefer a bettr alternative

Comment: `less`, `more`, `cat`, `vi` ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the use of a text editor.  These are often times installed by default on *nix systems?  Vi is usually available.

```
vi filename
nano filename
```

or

```
pico filename
```